# The exists() function

Tags: cypher, opencypher

This example uses the exists() function:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE exists((p)-[:LIVING_IN]->(:Country {name: 'Germany'}))
RETURN p.name
ORDER BY p.name;
```

How  is that query different than:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVING_IN]->(:Country {name: 'Germany'})
RETURN p.name
ORDER BY p.name
```

Why should I use the `exist()` function?

I don't understand what is the difference or use case for the exist() function.

Answer (score 1):

The `MATCH` clause must look for and remember all matches. But the `EXISTS` function only needs to find a single pattern match to return `TRUE`. So `EXISTS` can speed up a query.

Also, in your first query, no duplicate names will be returned (assuming every person has a different name). But your second query can return duplicate names (since the same person can be found in multiple pattern matches if he has residences in multiple countries).